# Getting wrong answer from data length calculation

Tags: python, variable-length

I have a list of 41 data from a functioned I defined, but I only want to access the first 40 of them. So, the index positions I am looking for are from 0 - 39

```
forecast_price(10)[:len(forecast_price(10)) - 1]
```

I also made it a variable for easier reference further on in my codes:

```
forecast_w10 = forecast_price(10)[:len(forecast_price(10)) - 1]
```

However, when I try printing the length of data in the variable, I still get 41. I feel like the mistake is right under my nose but can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

```
In[46]: print(len(forecast_w10))
Out[46]: 41
```

Comment: Just do `forecast_price(10)[:-2]`.

Comment: Re-check the length of `forecast_price(10)` once.

Comment: @enzo Tried to do so, but I still get 41 as the output :(

Comment: @Ank done so too, the length is 41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reproducibility, let's assume `forecast_price` is a function that returns a list of 41 elements, starting at a given initial value `x`:

```py
def forecast_price(x):
    return [i + x for i in range(41)]

print(forecast_price(1))          # [1, 2, 3, ..., 39, 40, 41]
print(len(forecast_price(1)))     # 41

print(forecast_price(10))         # [10, 11, 12, ..., 48, 49, 50]
print(len(forecast_price(10)))    # 41
```

Since you want to access only the 40 first values, use the slicing operator:

```py
forecast_w10 = forecast_price(10)[:40] 
print(forecast_w10)               # [10, 11, 12, ..., 47, 48, 49]
print(len(forecast_w10))          # 40
```

Comment: Thank you! I seemed to have complicated my own codes hahaha